# Supresss the 'no such file or directory' message from 'wc'

Tags: bash, shell-script, centos

I have this script and every time if the users entered the name of a DIR  show this  error
 `wc: standard input: is a director` 
 I need the way  to make  ever if the user entered a dir just ignore it  without showing any error message

```
Limit="$1"
if [ -z "$1" ]; then
   echo 'no Arrgument'> err.log;
   exit 0 
fi
shift 1
for file in "$@"; do 
   SIZE="$(wc -c < "$file")"
   if [ "$SIZE" -gt "$Limiit" ]; then 
       echo "$file is $SIZE bytes. Deleting.."; 
       rm $file
   else
       echo " files is smaller then the Limte  delete"
   fi
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before calling `wc -c` to calculate the number of bytes in `$file` (which *potentially* could be a very slow way of getting the size of a file, unless the implementation is smart, which it is on Linux; consider using `stat -L -c %s "$file"` instead on Linux, which is guaranteed to not need to read the entire file), test whether it's a regular file, and skip it if it's not:

```
[[ ! -f $file ]] && continue
```

The `-f` test would be *true* if the file is a regular file or a symbolic link to a regular file.  The test is negated with `!` and the `continue` statement is executed if the whole test is true (the file is not a regular file or a line to one), skipping ahead to the next iteration of the loop.

---

Note that you *need* to double quote `$file` in the call to `rm`, or the script would do the wrong thing if given arguments that contain spaces, tabs or newlines. It would additionally delete more than you bargained for if any filename contained a filename globbing character (for example, if a file was called `*`).

You also need to use `--` in front of the argument to be able to successfully delete files whose names start with a dash:

```
rm -- "$file"
```

Also, to `shift` a single argument, you need just `shift`.

And use `exit 1` to exit with an error. It's not clear why you print to a log file here when you could instead print to standard error (with `>&2`) and then redirect the scripts error output to an error log when invoking the script.

---

An alternative implementation of your script:

```
#!/bin/sh

sz=${1:?Error: size is missing}
shift

[ "$#" -gt 0 ] && find -L "$@" -maxdepth 0 -type f -size +"$sz"c -delete
```

This uses `find` to test the arguments to see whether they are regular files, larger than a particular size, and deletes them if that's the case. The `-maxdepth 0` test stops the `find` command from considering anything but the search paths themselves (it will not descend into directories).

The error message for missing size argument is handled by a standard parameter substitution, `${variable:?error message}`, which will terminate the script with `error message` if the given `variable` is empty or unset.

Comment: It might help to see the homework assignment question that is prompting this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/61837388/600988

Comment: In my Kubuntu `wc -c` uses `fstat(2)` if possible. Even `<regular_file wc -c` does not read the entire file. Other implementations may not be that clever though.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Yes, OpenBSD `wc` does the same, but it can't be guaranteed on all Unices.  Using `stat` (or `find ... -size` as I do at the end) would be quicker.

Comment: If using GNU `stat`, you need the `-L` option for it to be equivalent to `wc -c`. Same for `find`. See also the standard `-prune` instead GNU-style `-maxdepth 0`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thanks! Let's assume GNU tools here (Q is tagged with [tag:centos]).